# Code Keeps Timing Out

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

So, we've got this set of code that, for some reason, keeps timing out.  It's not the stored procedure that it's running, because that runs fine.  Also, if we remove the parameter from the c# code, the code runs.  The parameter keeps breaking (causing it to time out) and we can't figure out why.

c#:

```
public static PTWViewList GetList(int studynumber) 
        {
            PTWViewList tempList = new PTWViewList();
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.cnARDB))
            {
                string spName = "ardb.PTWViewSelect";
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, myConnection);
                myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@study", studynumber); 

                myConnection.Open();
                using (NullableDataReader myReader = new NullableDataReader(myCommand.ExecuteReader())) /*this is where the code times out*/
                {
                    tempList = new PTWViewList();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        tempList.Add(FillDataRecord(myReader));
                    }
                    myReader.Close();
                }
            }

            tempList.ListCount = tempList.Count;
            return tempList;
        }
```

stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ardb].[PTWViewSelect] 
    @studynumber int = NULL,
    @quoteid uniqueidentifier = NULL,
    @lineitemid uniqueidentifier = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        [Study]
        ,[LineItemID]
        ,[QuoteID]
        ,[Total]
        ,[COOP]
        ,[VendorCost]
        ,[CustCost]
        ,[LineItemNumber]
        ,[StudyTypeCode]
        ,[GroupLeader]
        ,[PTWDate]
        ,[PONumber]
        ,[POStatus]
        ,[StudyDirector]
        ,[SL_DESC_L]
        ,[SL_Code]
        ,ProjectDescription
        ,CreatedBy
        ,chARProcess
        ,CODate
    FROM
        [ARDB].[dbo].[PTWView]
    WHERE
        (@studynumber is null or StudyNumber=@studynumber)
        AND (@quoteid is null or QuoteID=@quoteid)
        AND (@lineitemid is null or LineItemID = @lineitemid)
END
```

Comment: If you add the parameters back and SQL starts timing out, I would say you have a problem with your database. Have you indexed the relevant columns?

Comment: What happens if you `exec PTWViewSelect 4711` in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Does it timeout at the same point each time? ie...30 seconds? What is the last line of code executed before the timeout occurs? Has the stored proc been run locally or remotely when you say it runs fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting arithabort off made the sp take 45 seconds as opposed to 1.  setting it back on changed it back to 1.  I updated the stored procedure to set it on, no change in the app.  Changed it to off, no change.  I then removed the update and then the app worked fine.

I believe what happened is that updating the stored procedure caused it to recompile, fixing the issue.  I'm not 100% sure on this though.

Comment: `I updated the stored procedure to set it on`   this is a connection setting, not an proc setting, you have to do it in the connection from .NET

Comment: example...MyConnection.Execute "SET ARITHABORT ON"

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studynumber", studynumber);
```

instead of:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@study", studynumber);
```

Comment: Helps to use the correct parameter names. But it could also be partially mock'd code. But even still it should throw an error about the bad param and the error would not be a timeout error.

Comment: Sorry, copied the stored procedure off of the wrong server (talked with dev and he concured that this is not the issue)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
If passing parameters is the problem, then it comes down to how much time the stored procedure takes to execute. Default timeout for SQL server is usually 120 secs. You can add "Connect Timeout" to increase timeout in your DB connection string and check out.

** Old Answer -- Ignore **
Without stack trace, and taking your word that the stored procedure is fine, I am guessing that it is timing out due to the connection failure. The code is unable to connect to your DB server and hence timing out.

Comment: @Oded - Oops missed out that in question - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing could be the `ARITHABORT` setting, set it to ON...NET defaults to OFF

run the proc in SSMS with ARITHABORT set to OFF and see if it runs slower now like from .NET

example

```
MyConnection.Execute "SET ARITHABORT ON"
```

Another thing is that your WHERE clause is not optimal, take a look at [Do you use Column=@Param OR @Param IS NULL in your WHERE clause? Don't, it doesn't perform](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/do-you-use-column-param-or-param-is-null)

does the proc run slow with parameters in SSMS? Can you show the execution plan?

Comment: `SET ARITHABORT ON` to On makes no functional difference in SQL Server 2005+ If `ANSI_WARNINGS` are on then it will behave as though it is on anyway. The one difference it does make is in use as a plan cache key. So if different behaviour is observed between executions with it set on or off this is probably a parameter sniffing issue.